# background color in body does not change everywhere

Tags: html, css

The problem is that only the margin is transforming not the background color of the header, footer...

I am wishing to change the colour of the header & footer as well, but am having issues doing so.

I've looked up a lot on google, but I haven't found a solution for my problem.

screenshot: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZZMY.png)

html code:     [HTML Code](https://pastebin.com/7NDSyt0K)

css code:     [CSS Code](https://pastebin.com/CdrAr0pf)

[image]

```css
* {
    background-color: #009cab;
    color: #000;
}
 
body {
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 880px;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
    padding: 25px;
    border: 5px solid #000;
    border-top-right-radius: 50px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 50px;
    background-image: url(../afb/boven.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: bottom right;
}
 
h1 {
    font-size: 60px;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
}
 
p {
    text-align: justify;
}
 
img {
    border-color: #fff;
}
 
figure {
    padding-top: 20px;
    background-color: #009cab;
    color: #fff;
    width: 450px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    border: 5px solid #ccc;
    border-top-right-radius: 50px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="nl">
 
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Thomas Morus</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/CSS_Deel_2_Oefening_3_basis.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/CSS_Deel_2_Oefening_3_printer.css" media="print">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/CSS_Deel_2_Oefening_3_grootscherm.css" media="screen and (min-width:700px)">
</head>
 
<body>
 
 
    <header>
        <h1>Thomas Morus</h1>
        <nav>
            <h2 class="cursief">Navigatie</h2>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#leven">Leven</a></li>
                <li><a href="#werken">Werken</a></li>
                <li><a href="#zalig">Zalig</a></li>
                <li><a href="#scholen">Scholen</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
 
    <article>
        <h2>De mens Thomas More</h2>
        <p>Thomas More was een Engels renaissance-humanist, jurist, filosoof en staatsman. Hij werd beroemd door zijn boek Utopia (1516), waarin hij het politieke systeem van een ideale niet-bestaande eilandstaat beschrijft. De beschrijving van Utopia vertoont overeenkomsten met een socialistische heilstaat. More gebruikte dit boek om zich af te zetten tegen het economische en politieke beleid van Engeland. Hij werd in 1935 door paus Pius XI heilig verklaard en wordt gevierd op 22 juni.</p>
        <figure><img src="afb/thomasmore.jpg" alt="Schilderij Thomas More">
            <figcaption><span class="cursief vet">Afbeelding 1:</span> Thomas More</figcaption>
        </figure>
 
        <section>
            <h3 id="leven"> Leven</h3>
 
            <p>More werd geboren op 7 februari 1478 in een Londens burgergezin. Zijn vader was rechter, zijn moeder stierf waarschijnlijk toen More jong was. Als tiener werd hij page van John Morton, de Lord Chancellor en aartsbisschop van Canterbury. More genoot daar een goede opvoeding en kwam in contact met een bredere cultuur. Na zijn verblijf bij John Morton ging More naar Oxford, waar hij van 1492 tot 1494 artes (schone letteren) studeerde. Na twee jaar werd hij door zijn vader teruggeroepen naar Londen om er advocaat te worden.</p>
 
            <p>Tussen 1494 en 1501 studeerde More dan ook rechten en trad hij toe tot de kringen van Engelse humanisten zoals John Holt, John Colet en William Grocyn. Hij ontwikkelde zich tot een veelzijdig humanist en bestudeerde de bijbel in zijn oorspronkelijke taal. Daarvoor onderzocht hij werken van de kerkvaders Hiëronymus en Augustinus. Daarnaast werd More ook onderwezen over de brieven van Paulus en studeerde hij Grieks bij William Grocyn. In 1499 ontmoette hij dan Erasmus, volgens More was dat een scharnierpunt in zijn leven.</p>
 
            <p>In 1504 werd More lid van het Engelse Lagerhuis. Erasmus verbleef vaak bij More thuis en schreef daar in 1509 de aan More opgedragen Lof der zotheid. Ook voerden More en Erasmus onderling een uitgebreide correspondentie. In 1510 werd More rechter en kort daarna undersheriff van Londen. In 1511 hertrouwde hij met Alice Middleton.</p>
 
            <p>Als gezant van koning Hendrik VIII van Engeland verbleef hij in 1515 in Brugge en bezocht ook Brussel, Mechelen en Antwerpen. In 1518 werd hij lid van de Privy Council en secretaris van de koning. In 1521 werd hij in de adelstand verheven (sir Thomas More) en benoemd tot onderschatbewaarder. Hij leidde verschillende diplomatieke missies. In 1529 volgde hij Thomas Wolsey op als lord chancellor en bekleedde deze post tot 1532. More werd zo een vooraanstaand politicus, niet alleen in Engeland, maar ook in de rest van Europa. Daarnaast was hij een beroemd humanist en geleerde, en stond hij bekend als een wijs en fijnzinnig mens.</p>
        </section>
 
        <section>
            <h3 id="werken">Werken</h3>
 
            <p>Naast jurist en staatsman was Thomas More ook wetenschapper en schrijver. Hij schreef zowel in het Engels als in het Latijn. Naast zijn beroemde werk Utopia, schreef hij ook gedichten, religieuze polemieken, brieven en een geschiedkundig werk.</p>
        </section>
 
        <section>
            <h3 id="zalig">Zalig- en heiligverklaring</h3>
 
            <p>In 1886 werd More zalig verklaard door paus Leo XIII. Zijn heiligverklaring vond plaats op 19 mei 1935 (samen met die van John Fisher), 400 jaar na zijn executie. Zijn feestdag werd vastgelegd op 9 juli. Na het Tweede Vaticaans Concilie werd deze datum verplaatst naar 22 juni, maar in de buitengewone vorm van de Romeinse ritus geldt nog steeds 9 juli als feestdag. 22 juni is eveneens de feestdag van Sint-John Fisher, de enige bisschop die tijdens de Engelse reformatie loyaal aan de paus bleef. Sint-Thomas More is de beschermheilige van staatslieden en politici.[3] In 1980 voegde de Anglicaanse Kerk More en Fisher toe aan de lijst van heiligen en helden van de christelijke Kerk met feestdag op 6 juli (zijn sterfdag).</p>
        </section>
 
        <section>
            <h3 id="scholen">Scholen die naar hem genoemd zijn</h3>
 
            <p> In het Verenigd Koninkrijk, de Verenigde Staten, Canada en Zuid-Afrika dragen heel wat basisscholen en colleges de naam van Thomas More.</p>
 
            <p>Sinds 11 juli 2012 vormen in Vlaanderen de voormalige <span class="vet">Katholieke Hogeschool Kempen, Lessius Antwerpen en Lessius Mechelen</span>, waaronder het De Nayer-instituut in Sint-Katelijne-Waver, de geïntegreerde hogeschool Thomas More. De hoofdzetel bevindt zich in Mechelen.</p>
 
            <figure>
                <img src="afb/campusgeel.jpg" alt="Thomas More Geel">
                <figcaption><span class="cursief vet">Afbeelding 2:</span> Campus Geel</figcaption>
            </figure>
 
            <p>Per 1 januari 2014 is de Pabo Thomas More te Rotterdam, los van de Hogeschool Leiden, verdergegaan als zelfstandige hogeschool onder de naam Thomas More Hogeschool. De wetswijziging die nodig was voor deze ‘defusie’ werd op 17 oktober 2013 aangenomen in de Tweede Kamer en op 3 december 2013 goedgekeurd door de Eerste Kamer.</p>
 
            <p>Het huidige Markland College in Oudenbosch, gemeente Halderberge, heette van 1960 tot 2004 Thomas More College.</p>
 
            <p>In 1958 opende in Den Haag het Thomas More College zijn deuren. Na een aantal fusies ontstond het Terra College, dat van naam veranderde na de moord op docent Van Wieren door een leerling, en uiteindelijk is opgegaan in de Scholengroep Den Haag Zuid West onder de naam van De Haagse VMBO Economie.</p>
        </section>
    </article>
    <footer>
        <p>Deze tekst werd schaamteloos overgenomen van <a href="https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_More">Wikipedia</a> voor educatieve doeleinden</p>
        <p>Naar <a href="#">de bovenkant</a> van de pagina.</p>
    </footer>
 
 
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 1):

After setting the background color of body here:

```
* {
    background-color: #009cab;
    color: #000;
}
```

You are immediately overwriting it here:

```
body {
    ...
    background-color: #fff;
    ...
}
```

Remove that `body{background-color}` line to fix the issue.

---

Assuming that you only want the box your content is in to be colored, you need to put it in a wrapper `<div>`.

You cannot put `border-radius` and `background-color` on a `<body>` tag like that and expect it to work. To see what I mean [check out this pen](https://codepen.io/Libruhh/pen/YzzrpwQ?editors=1100).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the white to green then use this CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: #009cab;
}
```

Otherwise please explain what color you want to change to what color. Or show a screenshot of how it is supposed to look.